# How to save order item custom attributes save into custom table

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

how to save order item custom attributes into custom table in Woo-commerce after order placed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use '`woocommerce_checkout_order_processed`' action or '`woocommerce_thankyou`' hook.

'`woocommerce_checkout_order_processed`' is called when order is being processed, whereas '`woocommerce_thankyou`' is called when the order is being placed.